# Cloud Functions support Async Await

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

It's possible to customize the package.json of a Google Cloud Function with:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node --harmony-async-await index.js"
  }
```

I need the async await support without using Typescript.

Comment: You will need to provide your own transpiler.

Comment: That sounds like an answer Doug. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you `package.json` inside your `/functions` folder. Now when you deploy it, you'll be using the Node v8 runtime which supports async / await syntax.

```
"engines": {
    "node": "8"
  }
```